# Laravel 8 Form validation dependent to other form

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, laravel-8

I have a select box that has the option of yes and no, if the selected option is yes the percentage form will be required otherwise the percentage is not required.

this is the select form

```xml
<select name="downpaymentrequired">
  <option  value="1">Yes</option>                                                      
  <option selected="selected" value="0">No</option>                                                                                                               
</select>                                                
<span>
  @error('downpaymentrequired'){{ $message }}@enderror
</span>
```

this is the percentage form

```xml
<input min="0"  maxlength="3" disabled id="downPaymentPercentageForm" type="text" name="downPaymentPercentage">
<span class="text-danger">
  @error('downPaymentPercentage'){{ $message }}@enderror
</span>
```

and this is my validation

```
'downpaymentrequired' => 'required|bool',
'downPaymentPercentage' => 'exclude_if:downpaymentrequired,false|required|numeric|between:1,100'
```

Hello guys, please help me i know it might be a duplicate but the problem is the existing answer doesn't work for me I hope you help me.

Comment: even though i choose No in select form it always has validation message in percentage form. i hope you help me guys

Answer (score 1):

```
 'downpaymentrequired' => 'required|bool',
 'downPaymentPercentage' => 'required_if:downpaymentrequired,1|numeric|between:1,100'
```

I just see the answer. I decided not to delete this post because someone might have the same problem as this. I hope this code will help you. you're welcome.